# Xamarin.Forms 5.0.0.2622 compilation error about styles.xml

Tags: c#, android, .net, xamarin

Using Jetbrains Rider on MacOS Sonoma and Visual Studio 2022 on Windows 11 with latest updates.

The following errors started cropping up on both of my dev environments once I upgraded to Xamarin.Forms 5.0.0.2622 (along with all the other packages I upgraded):

```
0>styles.xml(13): Error APT2260 : style attribute 'attr/colorAccent (aka com.ScanAndBroadcastSample:attr/colorAccent)' not found.
0>Xamarin.Android.Aapt2.targets(156,3): Error APT2260 : resource style/Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.DarkActionBar (aka com.ScanAndBroadcastSample:style/Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.DarkActionBar) not found.
0>styles.xml(11): Error APT2260 : style attribute 'attr/windowNoTitle (aka com.ScanAndBroadcastSample:attr/windowNoTitle)' not found.
0>styles.xml(11): Error APT2260 : style attribute 'attr/windowActionBar (aka com.ScanAndBroadcastSample:attr/windowActionBar)' not found.
0>styles.xml(11): Error APT2260 : style attribute 'attr/colorPrimary (aka com.ScanAndBroadcastSample:attr/colorPrimary)' not found.
0>styles.xml(11): Error APT2260 : style attribute 'attr/colorPrimaryDark (aka com.ScanAndBroadcastSample:attr/colorPrimaryDark)' not found.
0>styles.xml(12): Error APT2260 : style attribute 'attr/colorAccent (aka com.ScanAndBroadcastSample:attr/colorAccent)' not found.
0>styles.xml(13): Error APT2260 : style attribute 'attr/windowActionModeOverlay (aka com.ScanAndBroadcastSample:attr/windowActionModeOverlay)' not found.
0>Xamarin.Android.Aapt2.targets(156,3): Error APT2062 : failed linking references.
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" package="com.foobar.testbed.mobileapp">
    <application android:label="Foobar" android:theme="@style/MainTheme" />

    <!-- as of q2 2022 the minimum api level to submit apps in google play store is 31 so we need to follow suit   -->
    <!-- moreover we need to target apilevel 33 (android v13) because xamarin.forms version 5.0.0.2622 requires it -->
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21" android:targetSdkVersion="33" />

    <!-- https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth/permissions -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" android:maxSdkVersion="30" />
    <!-- To manage turning bluetooth on/off -->
    <!-- Before Android 12, API Level 31 -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" android:maxSdkVersion="30" />
    <!-- Since Android 12, API Level 31 -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN" android:usesPermissionFlags="neverForLocation" />
    <!-- To scan -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADVERTISE" />
    <!-- To advertise / broadcast -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT" />
    <!-- To connect -->
    <!-- hardware option-->
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth" android:required="false" />
    <!-- To specify that the app can't be installed on a device without Bluetooth -->
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth_le" android:required="false" />
    <!-- To specify that the app can't be installed on a device without BLE -->
    <!-- Beacon / Location / Rssi distance calculation -->
    <!-- Before Android 9, API Level 28 -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <!-- Since Android 9, API Level 28 -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" android:maxSdkVersion="30" />
    <!-- To store and read Firmware -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <!-- To allow Firmware update service to run in background -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
</manifest>
```

My packages (latest versions at the time of this writing Q3 2023):

```
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.CommunityToolkit" Version="2.0.6" />
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Essentials" Version="1.8.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Forms" Version="5.0.0.2622" />
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.AndroidX.Browser" Version="1.6.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.AndroidX.Legacy.Support.V4" Version="1.0.0.21" />
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.AndroidX.Lifecycle.LiveData" Version="2.6.2.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Google.Android.Material" Version="1.10.0.1" />
```

Settings in xamarin/android.csproj:

```
    <TargetFrameworks>monoandroid13.0;</TargetFrameworks>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v13.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>
```

Styles.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<resources>

    <style name="MainTheme" parent="MainTheme.Base">
    </style>

</resources>
```

JDK location used in Rider:

```
% /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/microsoft-11.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java --version
openjdk 11.0.16.1 2022-08-12 LTS
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Microsoft-40648 (build 11.0.16.1+1-LTS)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Microsoft-40648 (build 11.0.16.1+1-LTS, mixed mode)
```

Things I've tried (practically any advice given in stackoverflow):

- Clean the nuget cache and refetch everything from scratch
- Reinstall Android JDKs (api levels 30 through to 34)
- Try to build with both VS2022 and Jetbrains Rider
- Downgrade the packages to different versions
- Clean the bin and obj folders and rebuild the project from scratch
- Use the '@android:style' syntax
- I even switched my own theme over to holo but I still get the exact same error

```
<style name="MainTheme.Base" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

The erroneous file that the build system complains about is this one:

Foobar.Droid\obj\Release\130\lp\113\jl\res\values\styles.xml

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <style name="scrollViewScrollBars">
        <item name="android:scrollbars">vertical|horizontal</item>
    </style>
    <style name="collectionViewTheme">
        <item name="collectionViewStyle">@style/scrollViewScrollBars</item>
    </style>
    <style name="scrollViewTheme">
        <item name="scrollViewStyle">@style/scrollViewScrollBars</item>
    </style>
    <style name="MainTheme" parent="MainTheme.Base"></style><!-- Base theme applied no matter what API -->
    <style name="MainTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.DarkActionBar"><!--If you are using revision 22.1 please use just windowNoTitle. Without android:-->
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item><!--We will be using the toolbar so no need to show ActionBar-->
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item><!-- Set theme colors from https://aka.ms/material-colors --><!-- colorPrimary is used for the default action bar background -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">#2196F3</item><!-- colorPrimaryDark is used for the status bar -->
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#1976D2</item><!-- colorAccent is used as the default value for colorControlActivated
         which is used to tint widgets -->
        <item name="colorAccent">#FF4081</item><!-- You can also set colorControlNormal, colorControlActivated
         colorControlHighlight and colorSwitchThumbNormal. -->
        <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
        <item name="android:datePickerDialogTheme">@style/AppCompatDialogStyle</item>
    </style>
    <style name="AppCompatDialogStyle">
        <item name="colorAccent">#FF4081</item>
        <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Nothing helps and what really baffles me is the fact that the aforementioned file under obj seems to have most of its issues resolved if I manually tweak the name attributes to use the "android:" prefix.

What gives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of trial and error I arrived to the following solution by means of sheer experimentation - why this works I'm not quite sure though:

1. Delete the 'TargetFrameworks' property from your Droid.csproj
2. Make sure you have TargetFrameworkVersion=v13.0 in your Droid.csproj
3. Make sure you have the following references in your Droid.csproj:

```
    <ItemGroup>
        <Reference Include="Mono.Android" />
        <Reference Include="System" />
        <Reference Include="System.Core" />
        <Reference Include="System.Xml.Linq" />
        <Reference Include="System.Xml" />
        <Reference Include="System.Numerics" />
        <Reference Include="System.Numerics.Vectors" />
        <Reference Include="Mono.Android.Export" />
    </ItemGroup>
```

4. Make sure your xamarin nuget packages have these versions on your .Droid.csproj:

```
        <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.CommunityToolkit" Version="2.0.6" />
        <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.AndroidX.Lifecycle.LiveData" Version="2.6.2.2" />
        <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.AndroidX.Browser" Version="1.6.0.2" />
        <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Essentials" Version="1.7.6" />
        <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Forms" Version="5.0.0.2622" />
        <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Google.Android.Material" Version="1.10.0.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.AndroidX.Legacy.Support.V4" Version="1.0.0.21" />
```

5. Shutdown your IDE and manually clean the entire solution by deleting any and all 'bin' and 'obj' folders
6. Open a terminal on the folder that has your .sln file and perform a nuget package restore:

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\MSBuild.exe" -t:Restore your_solution.sln
```

7. Launch your IDE on your solution and inspect your AndroidManifest.xml - make sure it looks more or less like so at the top:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" package="com.your.app.id.here">
    <!-- as of q2 2022 the minimum api level to submit apps in google play store is 31 so we need to follow suit   -->
    <!-- moreover we need to target apilevel 33 (android v13) because xamarin.forms version 5.0.0.2622 requires it -->
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="28" android:targetSdkVersion="33" />

    <application android:label="(your app title here)" android:theme="@style/MyTheme" />
```

8. Open your styles.xml and make sure it looks like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<resources>

    <style name="MyTheme" parent="MyTheme.Base">
    </style>

    <style name="MyTheme.Base" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!--If you are using revision 22.1 please use just windowNoTitle. Without android:-->
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <!--We will be using the toolbar so no need to show ActionBar-->
        <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
        <!-- Set theme colors from http://www.google.com/design/spec/style/color.html#color-color-palette-->
        <!-- colorPrimary is used for the default action bar background -->
        <item name="android:colorPrimary">#2196F3</item>
        <!-- colorPrimaryDark is used for the status bar -->
        <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">#1976D2</item>
        <!-- colorAccent is used as the default value for colorControlActivated
             which is used to tint widgets -->
        <item name="android:colorAccent">#FF4081</item>
        <!-- You can also set colorControlNormal, colorControlActivated
             colorControlHighlight and colorSwitchThumbNormal. -->
    </style>
    
</resources>
```

Try to build the solution now in your IDE - the build should now be green again.

PS: If the build fails double-check with a debug-print that your $(TargetFrameworks) and $(TargetFramework) properties are both empty - if they are set to anything they might be the root cause behind your problems.

Answer (score 0):

> The following errors started cropping up once I upgraded to
> Xamarin.Forms 5.0.0.2622 (along with all the other packages I
> upgraded):
>
> 0>styles.xml(13): Error APT2260 : style attribute 'attr/colorAccent
> (aka com.ScanAndBroadcastSample:attr/colorAccent)' not found.
> 0>Xamarin.Android.Aapt2.targets(156,3): Error APT2260 : resource style/Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.DarkActionBar (aka com.ScanAndBroadcastSample:style/Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.DarkActionBar) not found.
> ..................

About this error you can refer to this case of Brandon Minnick: [Xamarin.Forms 5.0.0.2612 Breaks Android Build: Error APT2260: resource style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76899822/xamarin-forms-5-0-0-2612-breaks-android-build-error-apt2260-resource-style-the).

And try to update this file:

##### AndroidManifest.xml

In `AndroidManifest.xml` (aka The Android Manifest), update `android:targetSdkVersion` to `"33"`:

```xml
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21" android:targetSdkVersion="33" />
```

Comment: Yes I forgot to mention I already did that and still no effect - will update the original post to mention it